# AppSync and thoughts on being locked in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have been thinking about building a backend with graphQL.

The aim is to make the life of the backend team easier and iterate quicker rather then have to build REST endpoints or wss actions for each dataset retreivale.

GraphQL seems to be one of solution. We are very familliar with the Lambda environement and therefore in our research we found AppSync. I looks like a perfect solution, however I have some concerened around being locked in AWS and by designing the whole architecture around AppSync.

The beauty of serverless is that with the Serverless Framework, we could redeploy all functions to another cloud provider (Azure Functions) or even dockerize the functions for a deployment onprem.

I am concerned that with AppSync there is really no alternative in either other cloud providers or to easly do this onprem. Does anybody have any experience with this? Would it be more worth it to do the work to deploy an appolo server in lambda and build the connectors/listeners to the data sources our selfs with something like this: https://github.com/michalkvasnicak/aws-lambda-graphql/tree/aws-lambda-graphql%400.13.0#design-michalkvasnicak ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it comes down to how exactly the client of the GraphQL endpoint will secure data. One strategy is to secure an app with Amazon identity services like IAM and Cognito. Amplify's strength is secure integration with IAM, Cognito, API Gateway, DynamoDB, S3, and AppSync. A secure GraphQL endpoint on AppSync, for example. The data hosted in each AWS cloud service can be secured with Amplify and there are many other strategies too.

The [serverless framework](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets.site.serverless.com/whitepapers/serverless-architecture-use-cases.pdf) is a break through for serverless developer operations. The framework is beautiful. I don't disagree with your concern that Amplify generated cloudformation is not portable. Cloudformation is different DevSecOps culture than the Serverless framework.  Amplify's generated DevSecOps code simply lands in Cloudformation culture.

I'm awfully new to GraphQL on the cloud, FWIW. I don't have experience with  Apollo on Lambda. I cried, it looked difficult to automate the security though a seasoned pro may know. I certainly hope you get to a point where you never have to throw a single line of code away.  I'm not even close, yet.

Answer (score 0):

An easy entry point to the AWS eco system is to use [AWS Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start).

It has documentation guidance on security, GraphQL API, etc.